# iOS 7 Voiceover issue with UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, ios7, voiceover

I have a voiceover accessible app.  In iOS 6 the UIButtons announce something to the user when the button is clicked.  in iOS 7, when the user clicks the button, voiceover now announces "selected -  - and then announces what I want it to say.  I desperatley need to get rid of the "selected - " part of it, as it is ruining the flow of the app for many of the blind users.

Anyone have an idea on how to remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

button.accessibilityLabel = nil/@"";
button.accessibilityValue = @"announcement string";

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that in Accessibility traits for that specific button "selected" in not checked.
If you need voiceover to say custom messages you can write that in Accessibility Label 
If you want to provide hint to the user for the specific action you can add Accessibility Hint
and Voiceover specifies states or the particular control that is called as traits you can select as per your requirement.

Please clear of you are also adding accessibility through code as well ?